# How to detect whether a process or application is running and terminate the program if it isn't

Tags: autohotkey

So I am attempting to determine whether the process MultiMC.exe is running or not and if it isn't I want to end my script.

```
IfExist, Process MultiMC.exe
    ExitApp, 0
Else
    ExitApp 1
```

I've tried this but it isn't working.

Comment: This may help: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/49732-kill-process/

Answer (score 2):

Try the following "Process,Exist, act.exe", lifted from http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/50026-if-process-not-running-run-it/

I only show this so you see how the "Process,Exist, act.exe" is used in another script.

```
#persistent
SetTitleMatchMode,2
Loop
{
    Process,Exist, act.exe ; Sets errorlevel to process PID
    IfWinNotExist, % "ahk_pid " errorlevel ; Expression for ahk_pid
        { ; Block to do something.
        Run, C:\Documents and Settings\Pat\Desktop\act.exe
        Break ; Stops loop if run or it will continue forever.
        }
}
```